# Table rendering in preview but not in finished post

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview

At a [question just now](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4432155/what-formula-can-transform-the-table-on-the-left-to-the-table-on-the-right) the user was having trouble with the table he formatted not appearing correctly in the finished solution view.

[image: It's not rendering!]
[image: But it looks like it should work ok]

I don't know where to check for these reports first other than this meta, so I guess I'll get the ball rolling here.

Comment: Maybe one could check posts tagged [markdown-preview+tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markdown-preview+tables) on [meta.se] to see whether some of the bug reports there might help explain this.

Comment: I recently was editing a post which originally looked fine, and previewed fine, but got broken upon submission; I then resolved the problem by replacing some of its HTML markdown. I had the same issue with tables before. The commonality: HTML markdown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding an extra empty line after the colon has fixed the problem. I am not sure why this works but have seen this before.

Comment: Quirky! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 5):

Dietrich's suggestion in the comments also got me to a more central post at meta:

[Markdown table preview does not detect missing blank line before table header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359192/228388)